# Symfony2: How to get Authentication Listener config values into another service?

Tags: symfony, single-sign-on, cas

I'm working on creating an authentication provider for Symfony 2 that allows users to authenticate with the single sign on protocol called [CAS](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.0/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html).

My **Authentication Listener** extends from [AbstractAuthenticationListener](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.html). One of the config params is `check_path`, which is the path/route that triggers the authentication listener to authenticate the request.

I need `check_path` when I construct the URL to the CAS server (so CAS server knows where to return the user to), which is easy, since my custom **Entry Point** class is passed the configuration array when it's constructed in my security **Factory**.

The hard part is that I also need `check_path` outside of the listener, like during authentication inside my **Authentication Provider** class. I need it because when CAS server sends the user back to the app, it passes a "ticket" parameter that must be validated. To validate it, I send a curl request to CAS server that must contain the ticket as well as the original `check_path` that was used.

As a wrote this, I realized that I could get the current URL of the page request when I'm inside the Authentication Provider (since it's `check_path` that triggers it anyway), but that seems off, and I'd rather get the config value directly to re-construct the service URL. It also doesn't help me when I want to use `check_path` elsewhere, like when constructing a logout URL to the CAS server which also required the `check_path`.

**EDIT:** The `createAuthProvider` method of `AbstractFactory` is passed both the config and the container, but I cannot modify any of my services in here because they are not yet part of the container. Perhaps if I had a way to add a compiler pass after my services are loaded and somehow having access to the listener config?

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass check_path as parameter to your listener?

If it defined in your config or parameters file you can pass it to your listener like this:

```
your_authentication_listener:
    class: YourBundle\Listener\AuthenticationListener
    arguments: ['%check_path%']
    tags:
        ...
```

(If I understood you correct.)

Comment: `check_path` is not a normal parameter so this cannot be done. It is a config option for the authentication listener (see code for class `AbstractAuthenticationListener`).

Answer (score 0):

You can make `%check_path%`(or a namespaced version of it) a 'normal' parameter:
Inside of `DependencyInjection`, there are (by default) two classes responsible for defining and loading your bundle's configuration. In there you can also inject your configuration into your service container.

- `DependencyInjection\Configuration` is where you define which configurations are available in your bundle, what type they should be etc.
- `DependencyInjection\YourBundleNameExtension` is where you can load your configuration and also add them to the service container.

If you have not done anything in there yet, your Extension's `load()`-method should look something like this:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader(
        $container,
        new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
    );
    $loader->load('services.yml');
}
```

`$config` holds your bundle's configuration in the form of an array, so if we imagine your YAML config file looks like this:

```
your_bundle_name:
    check_path: foo
```

Your `$config` will look like that:

```
array( 'check_path' => 'foo' )
```

So now, all you have to do is add this configuration to the container. Inside your `load()`-method simply add something like:

```
$container->setParameter(
    'my_bundle_name.check_path',
    $config['check_path']
);
```

Inside your `services.yml` you can now use `%my_bundle_name.check_path%` like every other parameter:

```
my_bundle_name.security.authentication.provider:
    class: MyBundleName\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\MyAuthenticationProvider
    arguments: ['%my_bundle_name.check_path%']
```

For more details, have a look at Symfony's documentation [[1](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html),
[2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html)]

Comment: Thanks Iris. I'm aware that I indeed could make `check_path` a normal config parameter, but I'd rather not, since I then have to instruct users of my bundle to indicate the `check_path` both in the bundle config AND in the config for the authentication provider.

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand your problem? The `check_path` would be set in the bundle config and then passed to whatever services need it?

Comment: `check_path` is a special configuration option that's configured in your `security.yml` file for an authentication provider. Basically, I *have to* pass it in via the `security.yml` file, so also setting it for my bundles configuration is not desirable.